# Im usisng Masstransit Requst Response in asp.net core when I Send Request before get Response Request Canceling and throw Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit, request-response

I am using `Masstransit` ***Request-Response*** in `Asp.NetCore`
When I send **Request** before I get Response,  Request is getting *Cancelled*  and throwing this Exception

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

I have downloaded `masstransit` codes and debugging my project with it.
I understand `ClientRequestHandle` dispose and cancel requests before my response is received.

I checked *Consumer* side and it works successfully and sends Response as expected.

Comment: this is my code:  try
            {
                

                using (var handle = _getOrderInfoRequestClient.Create(new GetThirdPersonInsuranceProductAmountCommand(productId)))
                {
                    var response = await handle.GetResponse<ConsumerResponse<Money>>();
                    if (!response.Message.IsSuccess)
                        throw new DomainException(response.Message.Message);                    return  Convert.ToDecimal(response.Message.ResponseValue.Value);
                }            }            catch (Exception ex)
            { throw; }

Answer (score 1):

When using the `RequestHandle<T>`, you need to maintain a reference to the handle until the request is completed and the response is received (or a timeout or fault occurs).

You can simplify this by using a single line method, of:

```
var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<T>(request);
```

If you need to add things to the request, such as headers, etc. then you need to keep the handle around until it's completed.

```
using(var handle = requestClient.Create(request))
{
    var response = await handle.GetResponse<T>();
}
```

Comment: thanks Chris.but exception thrown after reviving response.